# Location of java file of JSP after compiled by Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat8

Recently i'm trying to figure out the location of the java file of a certain JSP file after compiling by the tomcat 8.0 server, but i'm quite confused since even after i accessed the jsp on browser, i still cannot found the java file of the jsp.
BTW, what's the difference between the tomcat installation dir and the server dir when using the eclipse, is there any relationship?

Comment: Try using `find`.  Don't know what I mean?  Type `man find` !

Answer (score 1):

The compiled JSP files are by default available in the /work folder of the Tomcat environment. There should be a subfolder Catalina which in turn has a subfolder representing the domain name which defaults to localhost. There in turn should be the project folder which in turn contains package hierarchy org.apache.jsp with therein the compiled JSP files.